# Determining the level of dissonance between two frequencies

Tags: algorithm, math, audio

Using continued fractions, I'm generating integer ratios between frequencies to a certain precision, along with the error (difference from integer ratio to the real ratio).  So I end up with things like:

101 Hz with 200 Hz = 1:2 + 0.0005
61 Hz with 92 Hz = 2:3 - 0.0036

However, I've run into a snag on actually deciding which of these will be more dissonant than others.  At first I thought low numbers = better, but something like 1:51 would likely be not very dissonant since it's a frequency up 51 octaves from the other.  It might be a screaming high, ear bleeding pitch, but I don't think it would have dissonance.

It seems to me that it must be related to the product of the two sides of the ratio compared to the constituents somehow.  1 * 51 = 51, which doesn't "go up much" from one side.  2 * 3 = 6, which I would think would indicate higher dissonance than 1:51.  But I need to turn this feeling into an actual number, so I can compare 5:7 vs 3:8, or any other combinations.

And how could I work error into this?  Certainly 1:2 + 0 would be less dissonant than 1:2 + 1.  Would it be easier to apply an algorithm that works for the above integer ratios directly to the frequencies themselves?  Or does having the integer ratio with an error allow for a simpler calculation?

edit: Thinking on it, an algorithm that could extend to any set of N frequencies in a chord would be awesome, but I get the feeling that would be much more difficult...

edit 2: **Clarification**:
Let's consider that I am dealing with pure sine waves, and either ignoring the specific thresholds of the human ear or abstracting them into variables.  If there are severe complications, then they are ignored.  My question is how it could be represented in an algorithm, in that case.

Comment: What you're really trying to measure is the beat frequency, right?  The weird thing is that as that beat frequency increases, at a point, it no longer sounds dissonant.  For instance, a perfect fifth has a pretty high beat frequency, but it seems to disappear and become part of the done of the interval.  In addition, that frequency is relative to the general frequency of the interval.  In short, I don't know how to quantify dissonance, but I think you're on the right track, if you factor in the frequency of the two notes somehow, in addition to their ratio.

Comment: Well, right now I'm looking for simple dissonance, or I guess it's called the beat frequency then!  However, I'm curious about your example.  Does it become "not dissonant" to the human ear because of some arbitrary weirdness in how it registers sound in certain frequencies (really high ones disappear?), or does it sound "not dissonant" because the beat frequency somehow aligns with the 2 notes creating it?

Comment: Excellent question, but I do not know the answer, sorry!  I would sit down at a keyboard with a spectrum analyzer to answer that question.

Comment: Although I can't answer your question, I can point out that in your example, 2 frequencies of ratio 1:51 are NOT 51 octaves apart. Each octave is twice the frequency of the one below it, so for 2 notes to be 51 octaves apart, the ratio would actually have to be 1:2^51. Hope this is somehow helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Chapter 4 of http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/mth192/pages/html/maths-music.html. From memory:

1) If two sine waves are just close enough for the human ear to be confused, but not so close that the human ear cannot tell they are different, there will be dissonance.

2) Pure sine waves are extremely rare - most tones have all sorts of harmonics. Dissonance is very likely to occur from colliding harmonics, rather than colliding main tones  - to sort of follow your example, two tones many octaves apart are unlikely to be dissonant because their harmonics may not meet, whereas with just a couple of octaves different and loads of harmonics a flute could sound out of tune with a double bass. Therefore dissonance or not depends not only on the frequencies of the main tones, but on the harmonics present, and this has been experimentally demonstrated by constructing sounds with peculiar pseudo-harmonics.

Comment: Let's consider that I am dealing with pure sine waves, and either ignoring the specific thresholds of the human ear or abstracting them into variables.  If there are severe complications, then they are ignored.  My question is how it could be represented in an algorithm, in that case.

Comment: Looking at the free pdf from the site mentioned above, for pure sine waves you just go by frequency difference. Guessing from the graph there, I'd say differences of from 0.1X to 0.5X their critical bandwidth will be noticeably dissonant. They say later that the critical bandwidth is roughly a whole tone to a minor third. So I'd be inclined to take the log of the two frequencies, convert this to semitones, and mark as dissonant any difference of 0.2 to 2 semitones. But if you have sine waves available I'd just try examples yourself, for different differences at different frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in *Chapter 4* of [Music: a Mathematical Offering](http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/mth192/pages/html/maths-music.html). In particular, see the following two figures:

- consonance / dissonance plotted against the x critical bandwidth in *4.3. History of consonance and dissonance*
- dissonance vs. frequency in *4.5. Complex tones*

Of course you still have to find a nice way to turn these data into a formula / program that gives you a measure of dissonance but I believe this gives you a good start. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/superposition/superposition.html

You want to look at superposition.

Discrete or Fast Fourier Transform is the most generic means to get what you're asking for.

Comment: Could you please expand on that? How would it yield a measure of dissonance? I understand very well FFT but I don't see how you could quantify the level of dissonance.